# KPL amazon Library only works when debugging

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, amazon-kinesis

I'm having an awkward behaviour when trying to send data to amazon kinesis data streams.
what happens is that i'm just sending one record to test but it doesn't work and when i normally debug it or send many ones. it works.

This is my implementation

```
@Bean
    public KinesisProducer kinesisProducer() {`enter code here`
        return new KinesisProducer(kinesisProducerConfiguration());
    }



    @Bean
    public KinesisProducerConfiguration kinesisProducerConfiguration() {
        String accessKey = System.getenv("accessKey");
        String secretKey = System.getenv("secretKey");

        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        return new KinesisProducerConfiguration()
                .setCredentialsProvider(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .setVerifyCertificate(false)
                .setRecordMaxBufferedTime(3000)
                .setMaxConnections(1)
                .setRequestTimeout(60000)
                .setRegion(region)
                .setRecordTtl(60000);
    }



    @Bean
    public FutureCallback<UserRecordResult> futureCallback() {
      return new FutureCallback<>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

                log.info(Constants.KINESIS_FAILED + t.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UserRecordResult result) {
                System.out.println("here");
                log.info(Constants.KINESIS_SUCCESS + "shard id" + result.getShardId() + "sequence" + result.getSequenceNumber());
            }
        };
    }
```

This is my service implementation

```
ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.wrap(new JSONObject(logModel).toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

```
 var resultListenableFuture = kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(streamName,UUID.randomUUID().toString(),data);Futures.addCallback(resultListenableFuture,futureCallback, MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
```

Comment: I don't know if kpl works with many records

Answer (score 0):

what i had to add this line at the end of my execution.

```
 kinesisProducer.flushSync();
```

finalcode

```
 var resultListenableFuture = 
 kinesisProducer.addUserRecord(streamName,
            UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
            ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    Futures.addCallback(resultListenableFuture, futureCallback, 
    MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
    kinesisProducer.flushSync();
```